# Dart: client.post() method in the http.dart package is hanging and isn't returning a future

Tags: http, dart, future

I am currently implementing a simple ONVIF client program in dart and am having a bit of trouble with handling futures in the http.dart package.

In my code below, the `client.post()` method returns a `Future<response>` (containing body/header/status code and so on...) and in my case I would need to receive this before the if/else statement, hence why I have used `await`. Trouble is the program just hangs and doesn't proceed past the `client.post()`line.
I know I might need to do a `client.close()` somewhere but I've tried lots of different ways and nothing works. Here is my current code with some comments to try and explain it a bit:

```
// The Variables: 
// reqSysDateAndTime is a soap message we are sending to the device.
// onvifDev is just a place where the device details are stored.
// probeMatch is a class that stores important info from the ws-discovery stage.

Future<String> checkXaddrsAndGetTime(Device onvifDev, ProbeMatch probeMatch) async {

  // Set up the client and uri.
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(probeMatch.xaddrs);
  http.Client client = http.Client();

  // Send the POST request, with full SOAP envelope as the request body
  print('[Setup]: Listening for Date/Time response...');
  Response response = await client.post(uri, body: reqSysDateAndTime);
  print("${response.body}");

  // Determine if the address is usable or not.
  if (response != null) {
    // Set this address as 'working'
    onvifDev.xAddrs = probeMatch.xaddrs;
    return response.body;
  }
  else {
    return null; // The address does not work
  }
}
```

I also know that this isn't an issue with the actual body of the request because if I do...

```
client.post(uri, body: reqSysDateAndTime).then((onValue) => print(onValue.body));
```

...instead, it will print out the response which I'm expecting.

I understand that this is probably a small fix that I'm missing but any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I did actually, though it was more a silly error on my part. Basically, earlier in the program I do a WS-Discovery to get the xAddrs of the device you see in this method. This Discovery probe sent back two xAddrss for the device so I just assumed that I could iterate over both with this method and choose the first one that works. Turns out I was wrong. The first xAddress was a link local address (starting with 169.) and when posting to this address there's no response, hence why it was hanging on that line.

Comment: I found this out by just doing some simple post requests in the terminal using curl. There is a nice method in the dart InternetAddress class https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-io/InternetAddress/isLinkLocal.html which will allow you to check for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To briefly answer my own question, turns out it was a silly error on my part where the address I was using was link-local - hence why it was hanging at `client.post()`. There is a nice method in the InternetAddress class [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-io/InternetAddress/isLinkLocal.html), amongst some other useful methods, which checks to see if the address is link-local or not.